# How do you use a WHERE clause to filter out duplicate data, Without hard coding?

Tags: java, sql

I have been sitting with this for a good few days, searching online high and low, but have not found a proper answer

My problem description, I need to filter duplicate data from an incoming .csv file, do a check to see if that data is already in the table if not then persist data, else do not insert data. My method, I read in a unique .csv file line by line, I use a preparedStatement that is suppose to use the WHERE clause to do the check for the duplicates.

The part I am having a problem with is, how to use the WHERE clause in my preparedStatement.

Below is some o my code to clear up any confusion.

PS: this is what the ,message_id looks like <329577443.1427052727657.JavaMail.javamailuser@localhost> there are thousands of them.

```
try { 
            dataRow = reader.readLine();
            while ((dataRow = reader.readLine()) != null) {     
                totalRecordsProcessed++;
                dataRow = dataRow.replace("\"", "");
                dataRow = dataRow.replace("<", "");
                dataRow = dataRow.replace(">", "");                         
                dataItems = dataRow.split(",", -1);             
                ExchangeReport exchangeReport = new ExchangeReport(dataItems);                                              
                //System.out.println(exchangeReport.toString());
                persistData(exchangeReport);                
            }           
        }
```

//Do a check in the insert method to see if we are persisting duplicate data
    public void persistData(ExchangeReport exchangeReport) throws SQLException{

```
    Connection connection = super.getEnvironment().getConnection();   
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;     
    String insertScript = null;     
    String skipScript = null;

    //ResultSet incomeSet;      
    ArrayList<String> rowVals = new ArrayList();

    ArrayList<String> dbList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    ArrayList<String> incomeList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String tempVal = null;


    skipScript = "select unique_ref, message_id, event_id from InboundCorres " +
            "where message_id = " +
            "";
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(skipScript);
    ResultSet dbSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    while (dbSet.next()) {
        rowVals.add(dbSet.getString(1).trim());
        rowVals.add(dbSet.getString(2).trim());
        rowVals.add(dbSet.getString(3).trim());
        System.out.println(rowVals.toString());
    }


    //List<String> incomeList = Arrays.asList(dataItems);                                                                           

    insertScript = "INSERT INTO INBOUNDCORRES(EVENT_ID, SOURCE_INBOUND, TIME_STAMP," + 
            "RECIPIENTS, MESSAGE_SUBJECT, SENDER, MESSAGE_ID," + 
            "CONNECTOR_ID, UNIQUE_REF)" + 
            "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertScript);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, exchangeReport.getEventId() );
    preparedStatement.setString(2, exchangeReport.getSourceInbound() );
    preparedStatement.setString(3, exchangeReport.getTimeStamp() ); 
    preparedStatement.setString(4, exchangeReport.getRecipient());
    preparedStatement.setString(5, exchangeReport.getMessageSubject());
    preparedStatement.setString(6, exchangeReport.getSender());
    preparedStatement.setString(7, exchangeReport.getMessageId());
    preparedStatement.setString(8, exchangeReport.getConnectorId());
    preparedStatement.setString(9, exchangeReport.getUniqueRef());
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();              

}
```

Comment: what is this statement doing (especially where clause)? `skipScript = "select unique_ref, message_id, event_id from InboundCorres " +
            "where message_id = " +
            "";`

Comment: Use distinct keyword

Comment: the statement should do the actual duplication check and then skip duplicates from being inserted into the table. Note the message_id column will always have 2 of the same message_id one for received and another for delivered.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement in skipScript is incomplete.

I would expect to see something like:

skipScript = "select unique_ref, message_id, event_id from InboundCorres " +
    "where message_id = :msg_id";

So message_id is the column name, and msg_id is a local String variable to hold the value we are looking for.

To get the value in msg_id, we could call a method called saveMessage() which would look something like:

```
public void saveMessage (final String messageId) {
    Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    values.put("msg_id", messageId);
    jdbcTemplate.update(skipScript , values);
}
```

Note that I have deliberately used three different names for message_id to make it clear what is going on.

Hope this helps. I realise my example used jdbcTemplate.update() which isn't like the code example, but the principle is similar.

Comment: It does clear up some confusion, thank you. Some more insight into skipScript, I left it incomplete, because I am a bit confused . What I essentially would like to do is something like this. ==> skipScript = "select unique_ref, message_id, event_id from InboundCorres " + "where message_id = :msg_id"; where msg_id is the list of incoming message_id's. Is there a way that I can check against this incoming data, inside the WHERE clause ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you user4810988, you helped me towards a solution.

```
skipScript = "select TIME_STAMP " +
                " from InboundCorres where unique_ref = ? " +
                "and message_id = ? " +
                "and event_id = ?";     
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(skipScript);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, exchangeReport.getUniqueRef());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, exchangeReport.getMessageId());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, exchangeReport.getEventId());

        ResultSet dbSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while (dbSet.next()) {
            rowVals.add(dbSet.getString(1).trim());
            rowVals.add(dbSet.getString(2).trim());
            rowVals.add(dbSet.getString(3).trim());
            System.out.println("Duplicates found ==>" + rowVals.toString());
        }
```

That is the solution that I was looking towards.